Issue with Modal: Unable to Close by Clicking Outside
I have a modal that opens when clicking a button. However, I'm facing an issue where the modal doesn't close when clicking outside of it. Here's the HTML structure:
Button to open the modal:
<div class="col-md-3 mb-3 text-center">
    <button id="spread-truth-button" class="faith-button system_page_button btn btn-custom btn-block" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#shareModal">Spread the truth!</button>
</div>

Modal content:
<div id="shareModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p class="centered-text form-labels">Broadcast the Arcane Cards</p>
        <div class="social-media-button-container">
            <button class="social-media-share-button" onclick="shareOnFacebook()">
                <img src="{% static 'icon-facebook.png' %}" alt="Share on Facebook">
            </button>
            <!-- Other social media share buttons -->
        </div>
        <input type="text" value="https://www.example.com/system_page" id="shareLink" style="display: none;">
    </div>
</div>

The modal opens correctly, but it doesn't close when clicking outside of it. How can I add functionality to close the modal by clicking outside of it?
What I Tried:
I first attempted to research the issue online and reviewed the Bootstrap documentation for modals to see if there was a built-in option for closing the modal by clicking outside of it. However, I couldn't find a straightforward solution within the Bootstrap framework.
Then, I experimented with adding custom JavaScript code to achieve the desired functionality. I tried various event listeners, such as click events on the modal backdrop or document body, to detect clicks outside of the modal and trigger the modal's close action accordingly.
Expectations:
My expectation was that by implementing the appropriate JavaScript code, the modal would respond to clicks outside of its content area and automatically close itself. I anticipated that this would provide a more intuitive user experience, allowing users to dismiss the modal easily without having to interact directly with the modal's close button.
